# Installing Google Cloud SDK with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, shell, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install the Google Cloud SDK which requires Python 2.7. I have both Python 3.5 and 2.7 with Anaconda. I am given a shell script and I would like to tell the shell script to use Python 2.7. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can change which version of python `gcloud` is using by setting environment variable

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=path/to/python2.7
```

then you can run `install.sh`.

Note that you should have this environment variable set every time you use `gcloud`, so you might want to set it permanently for your shell.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. It was my understanding, also, that gcloud was installed with the SDK so would the environment variable for the cloudSDK be available before running the install.sh?

Comment: Do you get same error? Yes environment variable need to be set and exported before you run anything in cloud sdk including install.sh script.

Answer (score 2):

An additional thing to add to @cherba's answer:

On Windows I found CLOUDSDK_PYTHON had to be a user level variable not a system level variable. (That's the first box if you're looking at windows system environment variables.)

Answer (score 0):

add the varable for python path

window+R -> sysdm.cpl ,3 -> advance tap -> evieronmetal varables

New click

- varable name :"CLOUDSDK_PYTHON"
- path : "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3\python.exe"